# Need to get current latitude and longitude from google maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

I have the below code which creates a Google map from an address variable in PHP.

Javascript:

```
function initialiseGoogleMaps(selector) {
    geocoder = null;
    maps = [];
    bounds = [];

    if (!selector) {
        selector = '.googleMap';
    }

    $.each($(selector), function(index, value) {
        var $this = $(value),
            mapOptions = $this.data(),
            addresses = $this.data('addresses') + '';

        addresses = addresses ? addresses.split(',') : [];
        $this.attr('id', 'google-map-' + index);

        maps[index] = new google.maps.Map(this, mapOptions);
        bounds[index] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        for (var i=0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
            if (addresses[i] === '') {
                continue;
            }

            initialiseGoogleGeocoder().geocode({'address': addresses[i]}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    placeMarker(maps[index], bounds[index], results[0].geometry.location, addresses[i]);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

function placeMarker(map, bounds, location, text) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: location,
        title: text
    });

    bounds.extend(marker.position);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    map.setZoom(zoom > 6 ? 6 : zoom);
}

function initialiseGoogleGeocoder() {
    if (geocoder === null) {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    }
    return geocoder;
}
```

PHP / HTML and Javascript fire:

```
$distinctPostcodes = array_filter(array_unique(Hash::extract($addresses, '{n}.Address.postcode')));

        if (!empty($distinctPostcodes)) {
        echo $this->Html->tag('div', '', array(
            'class' => 'googleMap',
            'id' => 'google-map-' . $uuid,
            'data-addresses' => implode(',', $distinctPostcodes),
            'data-zoom' => 5,
        )),
        $this->Html->link('Fix Map', array(
            'controller' => 'addresses',
            'action' => 'fixmap', $address['company_id'],
        ));
    }

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        initialiseGoogleMaps($('#google-map-<?php echo $uuid; ?>'));
    });
</script>
```

What I need to do, is when the user moves the map into a different position, I need to grab the latitude and longitude from the DOM and save it into a mySQL via a POST request.

I have looked in the DOM for the Google maps and it shows LAT and LONG, but they do not change when the map is moved.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen to a map event such as `bounds_changed`, `center_changed` or `dragend` (depending on what you exactly want), get the map center coordinates (if that's what you want), and pass it to your backend, most probably with the help of an AJAX request.

Available map events here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

For example:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {

    var center = map.getCenter();

    // AJAX request to your backend with the 'center' variable
});
```

Comment: I have tried to add the code as follows:                   $(document).ready(function() {
  initialiseGoogleMaps($('#google-map-<?php echo $uuid; ?>'));
   var map = '#google-map-<?php echo $uuid; ?>';
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
      var center = map.getCenter();
        console.log(center);
   });
 }); but I get the error: TypeError: c is undefined?

Comment: What's that? `var map = '#google-map-<?php echo $uuid; ?>'` Please provide your code **output** (what is printed by your PHP). That line should usually read: `var map = new google.maps.map(element, mapOptions);`

Comment: <div class="googleMap" id="google-map-544f9b30-2070-413d-aa52-0c4c0a004d1a" data-addresses="WR141AT" data-zoom="5"></div>

Comment: `var map = new google.maps.map(document.getElementById('google-map-544f9b30-2070-413d-aa52-0c4c0a004d1a'), mapOptions);`

Comment: ReferenceError: mapOptions is not defined